# previewing a db2 table failed: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

Previewing a db2 table through pentaho failed with the following errors, any advice would be appreciated:

```
2017/09/27 11:27:18 - Carte - Installing timer to purge stale objects after 1440 minutes.
2017/09/27 14:01:59 - C:\Projects\lovebuy\bbb.ktr : bbb - Dispatching started for transformation [C:\Projects\lovebuy\bbb.ktr : bbb]
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 - An error occurred executing SQL: 
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 - SELECT * FROM TB_CUSTOMER

2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.TB_CUSTOMER, DRIVER=3.68.61
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 - 
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1764)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery(TableInput.java:236)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow(TableInput.java:140)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 - Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.TB_CUSTOMER, DRIVER=3.68.61
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:749)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:66)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:135)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.c(uo.java:2780)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.d(uo.java:2768)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.a(uo.java:2217)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.h(bb.java:141)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.b(bb.java:41)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:32)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.vb.i(vb.java:145)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.ib(uo.java:2186)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.a(uo.java:3267)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.a(uo.java:708)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.uo.executeQuery(uo.java:687)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1753)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 -   ... 4 more
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - Table input.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - C:\Projects\lovebuy\bbb.ktr : bbb - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2017/09/27 14:02:02 - C:\Projects\lovebuy\bbb.ktr : bbb - Transformation is killing the other steps!
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by: SELECT * FROM db_virtualbusiness.TB_SAL instead of SESELECT * FROM db2admin.TB_SALE